# Free Software to Burn FLV to DVD

Tags: dvd, flash, burning, authoring, mastering

I am looking for a free software to convert FLV videos to playable DVDs. I have tried several of the different tools from Google, but I do not want a watermark or time limit on my content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **[DVD Flick](http://www.dvdflick.net/)** aims to be a simple but at the same time powerful DVD
>   Authoring tool. It can take a number
>   of video files stored on your computer
>   and turn them into a DVD that will
>   play back on your DVD player, Media
>   Center or Home Cinema Set. You can add
>   additional custom audio tracks,
>   subtitles as well as a menu for easier
>   navigation.

Features

- Burn near any video file to DVD
- Support for over 45 file formats (**incl. Flash video**)
- Support for over 60 video codecs
- Support for over 40 audio codecs
- Easily add a menu
- Add your own subtitles
- Easy to use interface
- Burn your project to disc after encoding
- **Completely free without any adware, spyware or limitations**